# Hidden DIV, Visible with Jquery Click & Google

Tags: jquery, css

I have a DIV that contains 300 words that are an advantage for my SEO.

The DIV starts out hidden (using css) and if the user clicks a well visible piece of text jquery will then change the DIV to visible.

There are no functionality issues here.

I wanted to ask if google will still take this text into consideration seeing it starts hidden? Or will this not be considered in total text of the site for SEO, google ranking and adsense etc.

Does anyone have an opinion on this.
I'm not hiding information, users can see if they choose to click and the text is valid and readable - not keyword stuffing etc.

thoughts?

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google's algorithms are a secret, no one can tell you for sure unless they are google engineers willing to tell you the secret.
Also, they have a monopoly, a bad one, so keyword stuffing shouldn't be a bad word around, do it anyway.
on a technical side, i don't think it should be good business for them to analyze at a jquery level each page, leave it hidden, because if the user has no javascript activated, they'll be reading the hidden text anyway.

Comment: Sorry i understood it the other way around, anyway, why don't you hide it with jquery to avoid any kind of bot hate?

Comment: I guess I could... just worry that it would show for a moment before jquery hides it... I guess testing will only know...

Comment: Try putting it a bit off screen.

Answer (score 0):

Actually under the webmaster guidelines that Google has set forth, which don't just apply to Adsense publishers, but apply to all publishers that have pages indexed in Google's search engine, Google does warn publishers never to hide text on purpose. The method you are using is a whitehat method, but you are using it to initially hide the text. Think about having a box with a preset length and if there is more text then you had a "more" button added so people can extend the box to read more and a "less" button so they can see less of the text by the box resizing. Don't forget to turn off scrolling. Is that maybe more of what you were looking for?